# Typeface adds extra space in the text box

Tags: adobe-indesign, typefaces, typesetting

When I use certain typefaces InDesign, in this case Roboto, the typeface auto adds spacing at the top inside the text box. This makes it difficult to align it perfectly with other objects. Is there some way to make this typeface always remove this spacing? (See image below) I know there are temporary workarounds, but I'd rather not have to do that every time I use the typeface, it can also be inaccurate that way.

[image]

Comment: Hi driverpizza, welcome to GDSE, "PROGRAM DATE:" is not Roboto, there's something wrong in your image, this "R" is from another font. On the other side it seems that you are using small caps, and these work as lowercase letters, leaving space for the ascenders.

Comment: According to my document it is Roboto, and small caps is off.

Comment: That top line looks far more like *Helvetica* than Roboto - at least the R does.

Comment: @Scott It is the android version of Roboto downloaded from font squirrel.

Comment: That doesn't mean it's a valid font. That R is exceptionally suspect. Just [check it against Google's page](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto)

Comment: @Scott I'm aware that on google font it looks different, either way, my real question is if there is a permanent way to fix that spacing or if I just have to use a paragraph style for each document.

Comment: Well, the "permanent" way to fix such as issue is to ensure you are using a valid font. Otherwise you need font editing software (Fontographer, FontLab, et al.) to edit the actual font file and alter the glyphs. That's typically more trouble (and cost) than it's worth.

Comment: @Scott Thanks man, was hoping there would be another way, but think you are correct on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is an InDesign text frame with [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) as the font. The character R is not the same as in the question, and the two dots are rounded.

[image: Roboto]

- Select the first paragraph and verify there is no **character
  style** applied
- Go to **Menu Type** > **Show Hidden Characters** to check there are no invisible characters with different specifications from the text
- Is it a Roboto font downloaded from the internet? Google font?

Comment: Okay, after some research, Roboto was also created for androids and is slightly different (can be mistaken for Helvetica). The Roboto I downloaded was from Font Squirrel. There is no hidden characters throwing off the type. I'm guessing it is just how the typeface was designed.

Comment: Irrelevant to the question I realize, but think this image may have used an old version of Roboto. When it launched the curled-leg R in the style of Helvetica was the default, and punctuation dots were square. Both have now been changed but the original R is still available if you click on stylistic set 3.

Answer (score 0):

For this reason I almost always set my text frame to offset by the Cap Height. The text starts at the margin and when I need to centre type in a frame it centres better, especially if it is in ALL CAPS.